# Samba writable or writeable

Tags: samba

I want to edit my samba configuration file - `smb.conf`

In smb.conf, does the parameter `writable` do completely the same as `writeable` ?

Comment: I can't verify but it's probably documented in the man page of smb.conf with the command: man smb.conf

Comment: Ok, I will take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/latest/man5/smb.conf.5.html go towards the end of **EXPLANATION OF EACH PARAMETER**:

```
   writable

       This parameter is a synonym for writeable.

   writeable (S)

       Inverted synonym for read only.

       Default: writeable = no
```